# How to have separate custom fields for tasks and sub-tasks in JIRA

Tags: jira, devops

How to have separate custom fields for tasks and sub-tasks in JIRA. For instance,

Task-A should have the following fields:
A
B
C
D

Sub-Tasks to the above Task-A should have the following fields
E
F
G
H

The sub-tasks fields should not be visible in its parent task and vice-versa.  There may be a few common fields, but I am quite interested in knowing about the fields that are not common in both tasks and sub-tasks, the reason being I do not want fields to be duplicated between parent task and the sub-tasks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure out how to achieve this.

Basically you can create separate screens that would include the required custom fields. These screens can be assigned to specific issue types such as Tasks, sub-tasks etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to obtain this and you need to be careful which approach you take.

- For each field you can specify for which issue types to be active or not.
- You can create different issue type schemes for tasks and subtasks.